# Knockout two way binding not working with Sharepoint modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint, knockout.js, modal-dialog, observable, two-way-binding

I'm trying two way binding (knockout observables) with sharepoint modal dialog

```
    var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = "Irfanullah";
    self.lastName = ko.observable('M.');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName();
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());


<button type=button onclick="openDialog2()">click me</button>
<div id="wrap" style="display:none">
<div id="d10" class="dialogHolder">
    <div id="kobasic">
        <h4>Editable data</h4>
        <p><input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p><input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
        <p>Full Name: <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i test this code on sharepoint wiki page its working good, but when i use same code on sharepoint dialog it shows values (one way binding)but two way binding/ko.observable() does not work (when i type something in lastname text box it does not update fullname)

```
 function openDialog2() {
    var e = document.getElementById('d10');
    var options = {
        title: "Test Knockout",
        width: 700,
        height: 800,
        html: e.cloneNode(true) 
    };
    mydialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

I believe that is alll becase e.cloneNode(true) but i could not figureout alternat solution

Comment: SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog manipulates the DOM, so Knockout isn't going to play well with it. It needs a custom binding handler.

Comment: You will need to use `applyBindingsToNode` to make Knockout aware of the new elements.

Comment: I tried to understand concept of applyBindingsToNode but i do not got it how it can be helpful, what i understand, SP.UI.ModalDialog copies the node, and later deletes nodes from dialog when we close.

Comment: I tried to bind through cutom binding but stand no where, can you please explain with little code how can i achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint dialogs I am using this approach:
(*note: jQuery needed*)

```
// create dom element
var element = document.createElement('div');
// apply my custom view
$(element).append('<!--my HTML -->');
// apply knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, element);
// show sharepoint modal dialog
var options = {
    allowMaximize: false,
    html: element,
    title: "My title",
    autoSize: true,
    showClose: true,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallback
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

So in your case:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
$(element).append('<div id="d10" class="dialogHolder"><div id="kobasic"><h4>Editable data</h4><p><input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /></p><p><input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /></p><p>Full Name: <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p></div></div>');
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), element);
var options = {
    allowMaximize: false,
    html: element,
    title: "My title",
    autoSize: true,
    showClose: true,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallback
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: thanks, I was also suggested to create custom databinder, i tried but i was not able to deveop such. can you please share your thoughts on it.